# ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor Callable() blocking my main Activity UI thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency

if the Callable() ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor is supposed to run in a background thread like Runnable() then why is it blocking my UI thread?

i thought is was supposed to run in a background thread like Runnable does.

```
 ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor stpe;
```

inside of onCreate

```
  ScheduledFuture<Integer> sf = stpe.schedule(new OtherObject2(), 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

  try {
    int returnedInteger = sf.get();
    textViewThree.setText("the returned integer is: " + returnedInteger);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

nested inner class

```
 public class OtherObject2 implements Callable<Integer> {

@Override
public Integer call() throws Exception {

    Integer integerReturn = 23;

    return integerReturn;
} 

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line `int returnedInteger = sf.get();` blocks to wait for the result.

Comment: do i have to launch a new thread from the inside of onCreate to put this one line in that new thread.  to avoid this problem?

Comment: what to do about this?  i just want to have the textView show the integer when it gets that from the callable

Comment: Call `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` from within the task with a Runnable that updates the UI, once the result is known.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `return integerReturn` in OtherObject2, run a special UI task:

```
final Integer integerReturn = 23;
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       textViewThree.setText("the returned integer is: " + integerReturn);
    }
});
```

No need for OtherObject2 to implement Callable, Runnable is enough. No use of submitting OtherObject2 by schedule(), execute() is ok.

Comment: that is true, but in that case it would be better to use Runnable. as you are not returning anything from the Callable.  the difference between Callable and Runnable is that in Callable you are able to return something.   If I am going to use runOnUiThread then what is the purpose of a return statement In Callable if you can't return anything without blocking the UI thread?

Comment: yes `it would be better to use Runnable`, and so I said: `Runnable is enough`.